# socket.Connect is not blocking in certain project, in other project it works as expected

Tags: c#, sockets, blocking

I have following code:

```
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.50.99"), 2111);
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Blocking = true;
socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);
```

Other end (172.16.50.99) is not connected. In a (C#)program with just this code, it will block. But the same code in another project (large), it will not block. I moved this code to the beginning of my program, but it still is not blocking. Is it possible that there are project settings which influence this behaviour?! I really don't have an idea what is causing this. I'm using VS2010, .Net4

Kind regards, Leo

Comment: you probably already checked this, but isn't this running in another thread?

Comment: can you show us the code where it doesnt block?

Comment: Is this under exactly the same conditions (same IP, same machine)? I can imagine the socket not blocking if it can determine it won't be able to connect without accessing the network card. By "not blocking" what _is_ it doing? What exception is it throwing?

Comment: you probably already checked this, but isn't this running in another thread?

Comment: you probably already checked this, but isn't this running in another thread? - no

Comment: can you show us the code where it doesnt block? - it is (exactly) the code from above

Comment: Is this under exactly the same conditions (same IP, same machine)? - yes, same machine, same code.

Comment: As mentioned above, need the SocketException.ErrorCode.  If there is an immediate CONNREFUSED or CONNRESET then it did not block, it failed immediately without blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it by creating a new solution and just copying all the projects from the original to the new solution. The socket is now working as expected.
Very weird. Only difference is that I have less references in my new solution (didn't add the unused references in the new solution). Could references influence socket behaviour? Or are there hidden solution settings?